# cannot install subkey on windows

Tags: rust, substrate

error: failed to parse manifest at `C:\Users\zalki\.cargo\git\checkouts\substrate-7e08433d4c370a21\d2a43d4\Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
feature `resolver` is required
consider adding `cargo-features = ["resolver"]` to the manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifically for the `resolver` issue - you likely don't have rust's latest toolchain. Try to update to latest (stable 1.54+) and try again.

But please do use WSL2: https://substrate.dev/docs/en/knowledgebase/getting-started/#windows

From the terminal, try the normal subkey installation process.

Comment: Glad to hear it! An upvote would be greatly appreciated to help others know this is the case looking :)